# Hadoop/YARN job FAILED - "exited with exitCode: -1000 due to: Could not find any valid local directory for nmPrivate..."

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, accumulo

I am trying to run a MapReduce job with Hadoop, YARN and Accumulo.

I am getting the following output that I cannot track down the issue.  Looks to be a YARN issue, but I am not sure what it is looking for.  I have a nmPrivate folder at location $HADOOP_PREFIX/grid/hadoop/hdfs/yarn/logs. Is this the folder it says that it cannot find?

```
14/03/31 08:48:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1395942264921_0023 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1395942264921_0023 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1395
942264921_0023_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: Could not find any valid local directory for nmPrivate/container_1395942264921_0023_02_000001.tokens
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what permissions are on the folder you are trying to access? Permissions in HDFS v2 are a lot more strict than in HDFS v1.

Comment: I created a user name hadoop who owns the hadoop folder, but I am running the operation as root.

Comment: @bdparrish did you solve this? I am also getting this error.

Comment: Same issue here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When i test the spark-submit-on-yarn in the cluster mode:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /usr/local/install/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar 100
```

i gotten the same error:

```
Application application_1532249549503_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1532249549503_0007_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000 Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: java.io.IOException: Resource file:/usr/local/install/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar changed on src filesystem (expected 1531576498000, was 1531576511000
```

there have one sugesstion to desolve this kind of error,to revise your core-site.xml or other conf of the HADOOP.

Finally, i fixed the error by set the property `fs.defaultFS` in the the $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml